# Convert Event based code to Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following code (simplified for posting purposes).

```
public class SomeDataObject
{
    public delegate void ReadyEventHandler;
    public delegate void ErrorEventHandler;

    public event ReadyEventHandler Ready;
    public event ErrorEventHandler Error;
    ...
}

pubic class ConsumerClass
{
    private SomeDataObject dataObject;

    private Task<List<string>> GetStrings()
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<string>>();

        SomeDataObject.ReadyEventHandler ReadyHandler = null;
        SomeDataObject.ErrorEventHandler ErrorHandler = null;

        ReadyHandler += () =>
        {
            for (int i =0; i < dataObject.ItemCount; i++)
                results.Add(dataObject[i].ToString());

            tcs.TrySetResult(results);
        }

        ErrorHandler += ()
        {
            tcs.TrySetException(new Exception("oops!");
        }

        dataObject.Ready += ReadyHandler;
        dataObject.Error += ErrorHandler;

        dataObject.DoRequest();
    }
}
```

The idea is that when DoRequest call is made, SomeDataObject will get some data and raise either the Ready or Error events (details not important!). If data is available, then the ItemCount indicates how many items are available.

I am new to Rx and cannot find any comparable example. So is it possible to convert this into Rx so that `IObservable<string>` is returned instead of `Task<List<string>>` using Observable.Create somehow?

Regards
Alan

Comment: Can you tell us more about the SomeDataObject API? It seems a bit strange. Is it valid to call DoRequest() more than once per instance? If yes, can calls be made while an existing request is in flight? Is it designed to have a single invocation but share results with multiple consumers? It feels like DoRequest should be returning a handle that can be used to consume the results (which could be a Task<TResult> or IObservable<TResult>). If there is an error, do you expect to be able to call DoRequest() again?

Comment: All this is important, because once an Observable stream has an exception it will not raise further events - so it might be better to represent errors in TResult rather than as blowing up the observable or task etc.

Comment: James, DoRequest can only be called once. It maintains internal state. It is actually part of an external COM library over which I have no control.

Comment: In that case Lee's answer is on the money.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matthew's answer is close but has some problems. First, it is eager, which is not normally in the spirit of Rx/Functional programming. Next I think that you will want to be able to release the event handles when the consumer disposes. Finally the usage of a subject should be a code smell, and this case it points to the two problems above :-)

Here I use Observable.Create (which should be your #1 goto tool in the tool box, with subjects being your last resort) to lazily connect, and also offer disconnection/releasing events when the subscription is disposed.

```
private IObservable<string> GetStrings()
{
    return Observable.Create<string>(o=>
    {
        SomeDataObject.ReadyEventHandler ReadyHandler = null;
        SomeDataObject.ErrorEventHandler ErrorHandler = null;

        ReadyHandler += () =>
        {
            for (int i =0; i < dataObject.ItemCount; i++)
                o.OnNext(dataObject[i].ToString());

            o.OnCompleted();
        }

        ErrorHandler += () =>
        {
            o.OnError(new Exception("oops!"));
        }

        dataObject.Ready += ReadyHandler;
        dataObject.Error += ErrorHandler;

        dataObject.DoRequest();

        return Disposable.Create(()=>
            {
                dataObject.Ready -= ReadyHandler;
                dataObject.Error -= ErrorHandler;
            });
    }
}
```

I would also consider moving `dataObject` to a parameter to the method too. Sharing state in an Async system is a source of problems.

Comment: Lee, this is exactly what I was looking for. I almost had it but couldn't quite grasp the concept. dataObject and its events are actually part of a COM library over which I have no control. I was looking for a better way of handling the events instead of Task<T>.

Comment: Your solution works beautifully but I am now questioning whether I should convert my code to this. Using Task<T> I can make the caller wait for the complete results - how can I do that using Rx.

Comment: See my answer to see I tweaked Lee's answer to show how to get a `List<string>` back and block to get the result with `Observable.Wait()`.

Comment: As per James' answer below you can just yiled a single value. I would have probably just removed the for loop and done something like this: `o.OnNext(dataObject.Select(o=>o.ToString())` and updated the signatures.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comments on Lee's (perfectly lovely and tick-worthy) answer, here's how to modify his answer to get a single `List<string>` response and block for it:

```
private IObservable<List<string>> GetStrings(SomeDataObject dataObject)
{
    return Observable.Create<List<string>>(o=>
    {
        SomeDataObject.ReadyEventHandler ReadyHandler = null;
        SomeDataObject.ErrorEventHandler ErrorHandler = null;

        ReadyHandler = () =>
        {
            var results = new List<string>(dataObject.ItemCount);
            for (int i =0; i < dataObject.ItemCount; i++)
                results.Add(dataObject[i].ToString());

            o.OnNext(results);
            o.OnCompleted();
        };

        ErrorHandler = () =>
        {
            o.OnError(new Exception("oops!"));
        };

        dataObject.Ready += ReadyHandler;
        dataObject.Error += ErrorHandler;

        dataObject.DoRequest();

        return Disposable.Create(()=>
            {
                dataObject.Ready -= ReadyHandler;
                dataObject.Error -= ErrorHandler;
            });
    });
}
```

Now you can block on this with:

```
var results = GetStrings().Wait();
```

If using .NET 4.5, then in an `async` method you can also do:

```
var results = await GetStrings();
```

Comment: Embrace the Rx James. Let that awful async/await and broken .NET Task  stuff die the death it needs to. ;-)

Comment: I refuse to rise to such blatant baiting sir! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below will do what you want. A ReplaySubject is used to ensure that the caller gets all of the results, even if the `SomeDataObject` events start immediately.

```
private IObservable<string> GetStrings()
{
    ReplaySubject<string> results = new ReplaySubject<string>();

    SomeDataObject.ReadyEventHandler ReadyHandler = null;
    SomeDataObject.ErrorEventHandler ErrorHandler = null;

    ReadyHandler += () =>
    {
        for (int i =0; i < dataObject.ItemCount; i++)
            results.OnNext(dataObject[i].ToString());

        results.OnCompleted();
    }

    ErrorHandler += ()
    {
        results.OnError(new Exception("oops!"));
    }

    dataObject.Ready += ReadyHandler;
    dataObject.Error += ErrorHandler;

    dataObject.DoRequest();

    return results;
}
```